# How can I .addClass('active') to a Bootstrap carousel particular item?

Tags: jquery, carousel

I want to do a modal carousel with Bootstrap and I build it with PHP...
I've got some images previews with this code:

```
<?php

  $directory = "images/*";
  $imagenes  = glob($directory.'{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,gif,GIF,png,PNG,bmp,BMP}', GLOB_BRACE);
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($imagenes as $imagen) {
      echo '<a class="modal-launch" href="null" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalvid" data-num="'.$i.'"><div class="prev" style="background-image:url(' . $imagen . ')"></div></a>';
      $i++;
  }

?>
```

I added a data-num variable so I can get the number of the image clicked to open the modal carousel on this item, and I want to do it with a jQuery with something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.modal-launch').on('click', function(e) {
        var num = $(this).attr('data-num');     
        console.log(num);
        $("#'num'").addClass("active"); // this doesn't work
    });
  });    

</script>
```

In the carousel I create the item lines using the code above to give they a number in the id:

```
foreach ($imagenes as $imagen) {
    echo '<div class="item" id="'.$i.'"><img class="img-responsive" src="' . $imagen . '" alt="" /></div>';
    $i++;
}
```

How can I correctly point to any particular item using the id or another type of parameter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `'` around the `id`. Therefore the code should be:

```
$("#num").addClass("active");
```

The only time you would use `'`, if you want to, is when attribute name is part of the selector, for example:

```
$("[id='num'").addClass("active"); //same as
$("[id=num]").addClass("active");
```

This format really comes in handy when you're looking to select say ***all elements with `id` starting with `num`, for instance***:

```
$("[id^='num']").addClass("active");
```

**UPDATE**

If `num` is a variable, then the code should be:

```
$("#" + num).addClass("active");
```

Comment: I understand.. but "num" is not the id, I want to point to an id="1", and if I use "#num" I would be pointing to an id="num", am I clear? sorry for my bad english.

Comment: If num is a variable then use $('#' + num).addClass('active');